# Pausing offset and commit in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, vert.x

I am new to Kafka and trying to handle a case where I want the offset and commit to pause and want it to get increase at some specific point(when the message is read successfully).

This is my consumer:

```
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.kafka.client.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaConsumerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("group.id", "my-group"); // Consumer group id

        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        config.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "0"); // Set auto commit interval to 0 seconds i.e. never. 10000 means 10 sec


        Map<String, String> consumerProps = new HashMap<>();
        consumerProps.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest"); // Start reading from the beginning of the topic

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = KafkaConsumer.create(vertx, config);
//        consumer.subscribe("my_topic").onSuccess(res->{
//            System.out.println("testing here");
//        }).onFailure(res->{
//            System.out.println("failed here");
//        });


        // Subscribe to a topic
        consumer.subscribe("my_topic", ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Subscribed to topic");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to subscribe: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                vertx.close();
            }
        });

        // Consume messages
        consumer.handler(record -> {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value());

            long currentOffset=record.offset();
            System.out.println("Current Offset="+currentOffset);
            //consumer.commit();

        });

        // Start the consumer
        consumer
                .handler(record ->{
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value());

                })
                .exceptionHandler(e -> System.err.println("Error in consumer: " + e.getMessage()))
                .subscribe("my_topic", ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        System.out.println("Consumer subscribed to my_topic");
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Failed to subscribe: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and this is the producer:

```
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducer;
import io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducerRecord;
import io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.RecordMetadata;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        config.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = KafkaProducer.create(vertx, config);

        // Produce a message
        KafkaProducerRecord<String, String> record = KafkaProducerRecord.create("my_topic", "key", "Hello, Kafka!");

        producer.<RecordMetadata>write(record);
//        ar -> {
//            if (ar.succeeded()) {
//                RecordMetadata recordMetadata = ar.result();
//                System.out.println("Message sent successfully. Offset: " + recordMetadata.getOffset());
//            } else {
//                System.err.println("Failed to send message: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
//            }

             // Close the producer with a handler
            producer.close(h -> {
                if (h.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("Producer closed successfully");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Failed to close producer: " + h.cause().getMessage());
                }
                vertx.close();
            });
//        });
    }
}
```

When I run consumer and producer, produce produces message and it i pushed to consumer as shown in the output:

output of producer:

```
Producer closed successfully
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output of consumer:

```
Subscribed to topic
Consumer subscribed to my_topic
Received message: Hello, Kafka!
```

Since, I have used the lines at consumer side:

```
config.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
config.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "0"); // Set auto commit interval to 0 seconds i.e. never. 10000 means 10 sec
```

and have commented consumer.commit() in

```
consumer.handler(record -> {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value());

            long currentOffset=record.offset();
            System.out.println("Current Offset="+currentOffset);
            //consumer.commit();

        });
```

I  was expecting the offset will increase but the "Hello Kafka" will not be shown in the output of the consumer, cause I want to pause it, and increase offset only when the the read is successful like here:

```
consumer.handler(record -> {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value());

            long currentOffset=record.offset();
            System.out.println("Current Offset="+currentOffset);
            consumer.commit();

        });
```

**My question summary:**
Even when I have commented consumer.commit(), how come I am getting  the message "Hello Kafka" generated from producer at consumer side? It shouldn't have been there right? It should have been paused as far as I understood Kafka.

**Edit 1:**
I also tried using this method but failed:
If I comment vertx.close() and consumer.commit() at consumer side, I am able to pause the messages, i.e., I dont get "Hello kafka" at consumer output. But I was expecting, to see "Hello Kafka" at consumer side as soon as I uncomment consumer.commit, which is not happening too.

Comment: first - you have two consumer handlers attached -- are you sure you are editing the code in the right handler?
also why wouldnt you get the hello kafka message? you subscribed to the topic and got the first message